# How to copyTo in OpenCV but keep original Mat?

Tags: c++, ios, opencv

I have two Mats and a mask, one is color and another is the same image in grayscale. My mask has black circles that I want to "cutout" on the grayscale Mat and have the color equivalent with. My intuition leads me to:

```
color.copyTo(grayscale, mask)
```

However, the copyTo "creates" a blank Mat for the destination so the output isn't as intended. It seems iterating through and manually updating a dst Mat isn't as straightforward as I'd like.

Comment: You  can't copy color image to grayscale.

Comment: convert your grayscale image to color image first with cv::cvtColor(grayscale, grayscale, CV_GRAY2BGR)